# Colon and Hash operators in Erlang

Tags: erlang, operators

The Erlang documentation provides a [complete list of operators with precedence and associativity](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id84275).

The first two operators in the table, `:` and `#` do not appear to be described anywhere else in the documentation. Technically, `#` looks like a binary operator in map update expressions, but that isn't quite clear. I saw no description of a `:` operator but might have just missed something.

Does anyone have a useful technical description of the `:` and `#` operators? (I started looking in the [Erlang Grammar](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/erl_parse.yrl) but there are over 700 occurrences of the colon, making a search pretty difficult.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it returns just 14 occurrences, much less than 700 :)

```
:~/otp/lib/stdlib/src % cat erl_parse.yrl | grep "':'"
'(' ')' ',' '->' '{' '}' '[' ']' '|' '||' '<-' ';' ':' '#' '.'
spec_fun ->                  atom ':' atom : {'$1', '$3'}.
spec_fun -> atom ':' atom '/' integer '::' : {'$1', '$3', '$5'}.
type -> atom ':' atom '(' ')'             : {remote_type, ?anno('$1'),
type -> atom ':' atom '(' top_types ')'   : {remote_type, ?anno('$1'),
bin_base_type -> var ':' type          : build_bin_type(['$1'], '$3').
bin_unit_type -> var ':' var '*' type  : build_bin_type(['$1', '$3'], '$5').
expr_800 -> expr_max ':' expr_max :
opt_bit_size_expr -> ':' bit_size_expr : '$2'.
bit_type -> atom ':' integer : { element(3,'$1'), element(3,'$3') }.
fun_expr -> 'fun' atom_or_var ':' atom_or_var '/' integer_or_var :
try_clause -> atom ':' expr clause_guard clause_body :
try_clause -> var ':' expr clause_guard clause_body :
inop_prec(':') -> {900,800,900};
:~/otp/lib/stdlib/src % cat erl_parse.yrl | grep "':'" | wc -l
      14
```

Also:

```
:~/otp/lib/stdlib/src % cat erl_parse.yrl | grep "'#'" 
'(' ')' ',' '->' '{' '}' '[' ']' '|' '||' '<-' ';' ':' '#' '.'
type -> '#' '{' '}'                       : {type, ?anno('$1'), map, []}.
type -> '#' '{' map_pair_types '}'        : {type, ?anno('$1'), map, '$3'}.
type -> '#' atom '{' '}'                  : {type, ?anno('$1'), record, ['$2']}.
type -> '#' atom '{' field_types '}'      : {type, ?anno('$1'),
map_expr -> '#' map_tuple :
map_expr -> expr_max '#' map_tuple :
map_expr -> map_expr '#' map_tuple :
record_expr -> '#' atom '.' atom :
record_expr -> '#' atom record_tuple :
record_expr -> expr_max '#' atom '.' atom :
record_expr -> expr_max '#' atom record_tuple :
record_expr -> record_expr '#' atom '.' atom :
record_expr -> record_expr '#' atom record_tuple :
inop_prec('#') -> {800,700,800};
-type pre_op() :: 'catch' | '+' | '-' | 'bnot' | 'not' | '#'.
preop_prec('#') -> {700,800}.
-type type_preop() :: '+' | '-' | 'bnot' | '#'.
type_inop_prec('#') -> {800,700,800}.
type_preop_prec('#') -> {700,800}.
```

There isn't really a better place for such info than `erl_parse.yrl`. [That's not my opinion](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-November/062387.html) BTW.

Comment: Oh my (facepalm) yes of course the tokens are enclosed in single quotes in the `.yrl` file. The answer is now apparent.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of them are proper operators. The documentation is misleading here. The # character is used in base-N-literals, as in 16#ffff, but that's on the lexical level, and in the syntax for records and maps, but not as an actual operator. The : character is used in remote calls, as in lists:reverse(Xs), but again, it's not really an operator - "lists:reverse" isn't in itself a subexpression with a value.

Comment: Technically they are operators. They don't need to be expressions with value, see the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_%28computer_programming%29 and also an example of a member access operators in C++ (similar to ':' in Erlang): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

Comment: I agree that the use of `#` in integer literals is part of the microsyntax, simply a character in a token and certainly not an operator. For map _updates_, it does look like an operator, though agreed that for map literals it appears to be part of the syntax. Good point about the colon; it is definitely an operator for accessing elements in a module.

Comment: To call something an operator, it should be possible to describe it grammatically as being applied to parts that have meaning in themselves, and you should be able to give the whole thing a well defined meaning as a function of the meaning of the parts. The # is close, but is only defined on the lexical level; e.g. "16#X" or "B#10" have no meaning. However, "M:F" has no meaning in itself in the language; only "M:F(...)" does. Similarly for a map update, you can't separate the # from the {...} part.